# How to make a rounded oval button?

Tags: ios, swift, button, rounded-corners

My goal is to make my button look like this:

[image]

minus the black edges around the button.

After reading quite a few posts, I see most solutions saying to use

```
layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
```

When I do that I get this:

[image]

It rounds the edges, but doesn't give me my desired goal.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Swift 3**

```
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.frame.height / 2

myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
myButton.clipsToBounds = true
myButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
myButton.setTitle("Connect With Facebook", for: .normal)
```

[image]

Comment: But the frame isn't updated yet if I put it in my view did load so it has a slight incorrect corner radius...

Answer (score 1):

You Can do it like this (For Example if you button is called button):

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.height / 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 15 you can have an even better appearance using UIButtonConfiguration by using:

```swift
var configuration = UIButton.Configuration.blue()
configuration.cornerStyle = .capsule
configuration.baseForegroundColor = .white
configuration.buttonSize = .large
configuration.title = "Connect With Facebook"

let button = UIButton(configuration: configuration, primaryAction: nil)
```

The `capsule` style will give you a much smoother rounding than before.