# UIView corner radius is sharp on small screens

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a button I'm setting its corner radius like this in `ViewDidLoad()`:

```
self.myBtn.layer.cornerRadius = self.myBtn.frame.size.height / 2
self.myBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The result is great on the iPhone X. Screenshot:

[image: X]

But for some reason in devices that has smaller screens (like iPhone SE) the corners are really sharp and the result isn't what I want to achieve. Screenshot:

[image: SE]

Does anybody know why is it happening?

Thanks!

Comment: @Krunal Any other idea?

Comment: try clipsToBounds instead of masksToBounds

Comment: @RavishaHesh Doesn't work...

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185598/3018183

Comment: My guess is the button was set up through constraints and you're setting the corner radius **before** the layout is finalized, so it is being calculated with a different size than the final one. Do this kind of stuff in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call your code in `viewDidAppear` (or better in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`)

It looks like you're using Autolayout. And it seems your button's layout depends on view's layout.
The problem is: the size of viewController's view may be incorrect when `viewDidLoad` called (but it's corrected before `viewDidAppear` called).